# I am trying to pass some json data from my django web app to a server running at localhost. Works fine at localhost but fails in production

Tags: python, django, request, urllib3

I have a server running at 127.0.0.1:16732.
I am passing json data to this server from my django app: `response=requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:16732/api/v2/requests', auth=auth, json=task)`
Works fine when I do it from my test python server on localhost.
But when I try to do the same from production server, it fails & give the following error:

"HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=16732): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/requests (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3e335006d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))"

Comment: check your firewall.

Comment: I did. Didn't help.

Comment: Where is your production? where is your server running on the same server, other server or your PC?

Comment: No, the servers are on different machines. I have a client machine with a server running at 127.0.0.1:16732, and I have a separate machine where django webapp server is running.  As a client I need to pass data from django webapp to the server running on my machine.

Comment: It works fine when both servers are on the same machine. The problems appears when they run at different machines.

Comment: If these are two different machines, you won't be able to use localhost, you will need to use the other machine's ip address. You can only use localhost when the two apps are on the same machine. So you need to make an api call to a URL like this 'http://<server_ip>/api/v2/requests'